# why Python keeps saying prompt is not defined

Tags: function

this is the code in Python, I really don't know how to do this, I am just a beginner and someone can understand my question and help me

```
def get_float(prompt, low, high):
    while True:
        prompt = input("Enter monthly investment:")
        number= float(input(prompt))
        if number > low or number <= high:
            is_valid = True
            return number
        else:
            print("Entry must be greater than {low}and less than or equal to {high}")

def main():
    get_float(prompt,low,high)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Could you please confirm if your code is tabbed correctly? It's hard to tell from the code snippet.

Comment: In `main()`, `prompt` *isn't* defined.  You shouldn't even be passing this as a parameter, since `get_float()` doesn't use it, defining its own value for `prompt` instead.  `low` and `high` are a more serious problem, where were you imagining that those values were going to come from?

Answer (score 0):

In main, you are passing in the prompt variable into get_float. However, prompt is not defined in main, therefore you are attempting to pass an undefined variable which is not allowed.

In fact, given that get_float reads the prompt from input (and not the value passed in), you do not need to pass prompt into get_float, and prompt can be removed from the function signature.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass prompt as a Function argument cause you are reading the value inside the function

```
def get_float(low, high): 
while True: 
    prompt = input("Enter monthly investment:") 
    number= float(input(prompt))
    if number > low or number <= high: 
        is_valid = True 
        return number 
    else: 
        print("Entry must be greater than {low}and less than or equal to {high}")

def main(): 
    get_float(200,1000) 
if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```